# Calling two methods in renderedCallback()

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, promises

In such a situation, is it possible that the result from method2 will be earlier than from method1?

```
renderedCallback() {
        method1()
                .then(result => {
                     // do sth
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                });
        method2()
            .then(result => {
                     // do sth
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be as both methods will be called asynchronously. If `method1` takes more time to execute it will return after `method2`. So the order is not guaranteed in that case. [Here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/aT1lR0qOpok0ziWa3nJ3/src/app.js) is a live example where `method2` is getting called before `method1`.

You need to chain them like this in order to maintain the order.

```
renderedCallback() {
    method1()
        .then(result => {
             // do sth
             
             method2()
                .then(result => {
                         // do sth
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });
    
}
```

Or use async-await.

```
async renderedCallback() {
    let result1= await method1();
    let result2= await method2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As you have used `.then` the two methods `method1` and `method2` becomes asynchronous in nature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Javascript will start execution of `method1` and will not wait for the response and execute `method2` just after that.

`.then` will be called when the response is available for `method1` or `method2`. But the order is never guaranteed.

For Order you can either use the `await` keyword as shown by Rahul, or you can chain them like this:

```
renderedCallback() {
    method1()
        .then(result => {
            method2()
                .then(result => {
                    // do sth
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });
}
```

Comment: The inner catch may not be required, when chaining then calls, any reject or exception will make its way to the next catch.

Comment: Yes you are correct,